# How do I change the FontSize of the data in my Silverlight Datagrid

Tags: xaml, silverlight, fonts, datagrid

I am trying to figure out how to make the font size of the data inside my Datagrid bigger.

My Datagrid XAML:

```
    <data:DataGrid x:Name="dgVisitData" Style="{StaticResource dgStyle}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" BorderBrush="LightSlateGray" BorderThickness="2"
                AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <data:DataGrid.Columns>
            <data:DataGridTextColumn Width="Auto" Header="Name" Binding="{Binding MemberName}" />
            <data:DataGridTextColumn Width="Auto" Header="Surname" Binding="{Binding MemberSurname}" />
            <data:DataGridTextColumn Width="Auto" Header="Member No" Binding="{Binding MemberNumber}" />
            <data:DataGridTextColumn Width="Auto" Header="Dependant No" Binding="{Binding MemberDependantNumber}" />
            <data:DataGridTextColumn Width="Auto" Header="Date" Binding="{Binding Date}" />
            <data:DataGridTextColumn Width="Auto" Header="Time" Binding="{Binding Time}" />
        </data:DataGrid.Columns>
    </data:DataGrid>
```

Using a style I can enlarge the headers font size.

Do I need to do something similar to change Fontsize of the actual data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<sdk:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}" CanUserSort="True" SortMemberPath="Name" Header="Name">
    <sdk:DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />
        </Style>
    </sdk:DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
</sdk:DataGridTextColumn>
```

or you could write your own datagrid style for your whole datagrid